# MySQL ODBC 5.3 64-bit installation

Tags: mysql, odbc, driver, mysql-connector

I have run into this Problem trying to install the MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3 64-bit Version; the 32-bit install runs fine.

I tried on Windows Server 2012 R2.
On my Windows 7 machine bothworked flawlessly.

[image: MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3 Installer Information]

I have found a lot of Posts suggesting - None of the tips worked:

- to install the 64-bit Version BEFORE the 32-bit Version
- to install the Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable package, both 64-bit and 32-bit (which I have installed for several years...). I even have the same Versions installed on the Server and on my Client.
- to replace some DLLs (msvc*.dll) in C:\windows\syswow64

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the last Suggestion brought me on the right track:

- to replace some DLLs (msvc*.dll) in C:\windows\syswow64

together with a Forum post suggesting to not use the installer but the ZIP from the Oracle site.

When running the install.bat from the ZIP I finally got the correct error message:

[image: myodbc-installer.exe - System Error]

So I copied the MSVCR120.dll from the C:\Windows\System32 on my Windows 7 machine where the Installation of the 64-bit Driver was working fine before over to the C:\Windows\System32  Windows Server 2012 R2 machine - where indeed it was missing! - and then Installation ran through.